# ROS package release status

Tags: ros, executive-smach, documentation, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If a package's documentation status does not list a specific release does that mean it is not supported in that release? For example, I'm interested in potentially using executive_smach, but it is not in the index for hydro on the wiki. Similarly, I would like to run the tabletop_object_detector but it is not listed for hydro either. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134201/ros-package-release-status/) by [B3l33b3r](https://answers.ros.org/users/12571/b3l33b3r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will find all released packages with their version number and the status of the Debian packages on the debbuild status pages:

- http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html
- http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html
- http://www.ros.org/debbuild/groovy.html

All documented packages will have the corresponding distro tab on their wiki page, e.g.: http://wiki.ros.org/executive_smach

E.g. `executive_smach` is released into hydro (currently version 1.3.1-0 as listed on the debbuild status page) but does not have documentation for hydro (missing tab in the wiki). The maintainer has only registered the package for release but not for documentation as you can see in the rosdistro file: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/7218e3476c4df432d79a93b3e12b9599a3a1597c/hydro/distribution.yaml#L949

You could poke the maintainer / fill a ticket to also register it for documentation.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1